# Line with arrowhead

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-css

I'm currently using `javafx.scene.shape.Line` to visualize fancy diagrams.

Is there a way to **add an arrow head to a Line**? I was hoping it would be possible using CSS. But unfortunately I cannot find it in the [CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

Impossible ?

Comment: you can use a *path* to draw an arrow and add it to the head of the line https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Path.html

Comment: @karim The easy thing with a line, is that I can move the entire thing after drawing it, using `line.setEndX`/`line.setEndY`. This can change the angle/direction of the line. If I use a path, will I have to rotate the arrow-head manually when I change the angle of the line afterwards?

Comment: You can wrap evething in a class that do the work for you and instanciate this class everytime you need a new lane with arrow